# Possible to use currying in this code example?

Tags: scala, akka

Consider the following Akka actor. Implemententations of this actor should need to override and implement `handleMessage(message: T)`. This implementation should call `executeQueryLookup` on its last line

```
abstract class BaseQueryLookupActor[T, U] extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case message: T => handleMessage(message)
    case message => unhandled(message)
  }

  def handleMessage(message: T) // Abstract method

  def executeQueryLookup(cacheName: String, queryName: String, params: Map[String, String])  {
    // Concrete method that contains query logic
  }
}
```

I realize there are multiple ways to achieve this without using any Scala functional concepts, but I'm thinking that it is also possible to achieve this somehow using a partial function or currying. 
If so, how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure i follow, but would it work to define

```
def handleMessage(message: T): (String, String, Map[String, String])
```

and call `executeQueryLookup` yourself in the base class, like

```
def receive = {
  case message: T =>
    val (cacheName, queryName, params) = handleMessage(message)
    executeQueryLookup(cacheName, queryName, params)
  case message => unhandled(message)
}
```

Comment: That would work, but not what I had in mind, I thought there might be an opportunity for currying, but doesn't seem to be. I will try this out, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you leave it to the subclass to implement a method, and you call that method, then there is nothing the superclass can do to enforce that the implementation in the subclass does some specific action. This has nothing to do with [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) or [partial functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function).

You will have another problem with your actor, since the generic type `T` is erased on the JVM: at runtime `T = java.lang.Object`. The match will therefore always be successful and the second case will never be invoked. You will have to pass along [type tags](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) both when creating the actor and with every message. A crude approximation would be to use `classTag` instead, since every JVM object has a `.getClass` method, but that will only match the outermost type and it will not help if you want to distinguish a `List[Int]` from a `List[String]`.